# get one month ago but always 15th of month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to get the month before today, but always to get the date with 15th.

i.e if today is March 11th 2014, I need => Feb 15th 2014.

or if the date is March 28th 2014, I need => Feb 15th 2014.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(Date.today - 1.month).beginning_of_month + 14
```

or another way

```
(Date.today - 1.month).change(day: 15)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using rails:

`(DateTime.now - 1.month).beginning_of_month + 14.days`

Refer to the [DateTime documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html) for more info.

Edit: Updated to reflect the previous month's 15th day.

Comment: that would give the fifteenth of this month, the question asks for the fifteenth of the month before this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new date object with last month's year and month numbers and 15 as the day:

```
today         = Date.today
one_month_ago = (today - 1.month)

Date.civil(one_month_ago.year, one_month_ago.month, 15)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
Date.today.prev_month.beginning_of_month + 14 # => Sat, 15 Feb 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
(Date.today<<1).beginning_of_month + 14        ##  => Sat, 15 Feb 2014
```

Or

```
Date.today.last_month.beginning_of_month + 14  ##  => Sat, 15 Feb 2014
```